# How to get JMX data without Java?

Tags: protocols, jmx

Is there a protocol specification for JMX? I found the JMX specification but it doesn't mention anything about how to write your own clients to speak with JMX. The documentation is about using Java functions/classes to access JMX data.

I looked over [jmxtrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans) but it's also using the Java functions/classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get access to JMX data without being limited to Java, you can use Jolokia:

> Jolokia is a JMX-HTTP bridge giving an alternative to JSR-160
>   connectors. It is an agent based approach with support for many
>   platforms. In addition to basic JMX operations it enhances JMX
>   remoting with unique features like bulk requests and fine grained
>   security policies.

Doing this you can use REST-style queries.

Comment: @user1529891 You need to have Jolokia somewhere, because otherwise it can not do it's work, yes. You deploy Jolokia combined with a Java (web) application. Then you can use anything that is able to speak http to query the application. As you are running a JRE anyway this should not hurt. I personally don't think it makes sense to mimic the low level wire protocoll of JMX (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/JMX_1_4_specification.pdf)

Comment: I just went through this with Python, calling JMX via Jolokia proxy (https://jolokia.org/features/proxy.html), running Jolokia with a standalone Jetty server in a Docker container. This required no modification to the target Java applications - you can pass the target URL and credentials on each POST request so a single proxy can comunicate with a number of target hosts' exposed JMX services. So I have one Jolokia server for several target Java servers.

Answer (score 1):

There's a web service jmx connector at https://ws-jmx-connector.java.net, but you still need to install the server side, so @Marged's proposal is the better solution. The Jolokia server install is pretty lightweight, you know... It comes as a war or Java agent so there's minimal fuss getting it working.

Comment: Sorry for being completely out of topic, but I can't think of any other way to reach @Nicholas. Nicholas, what happened to your seeallhearall.blogspot.com and what about the promised final tutorial for Netty? Is there any other place you write tutorials or articles? Please approve my comment I gave for your blogpost and kindly reply too.

Comment: @Amudhan; You shamed me into action, I confess. Will contact you offline.